# Join with lapply added to a list of Spatial Points Dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, r-sp, spatial-data-frame

I want to make a join beetween a list of spatial points dataframe with a list of dataframes. I can do the join with lapply, but I do not know how to add that into the @data information of each Spatial Points Dataframe in the list. How do I do that?

```
#libraries
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
#Spatial dataframe
nodes = nz_height
nodes <- as(nodes, "Spatial")
nodes@data$f <- c(rep(seq(1:2), 50),1)
#Spatial List
nd.l <- split(nodes, nodes@data$f)
#Spatial dataframe
df <- data.frame(f = as.numeric(c(rep(seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 1), 50),1)), 
                 g = as.numeric(c(rep(seq(from = 3, to = 4, by = 1), 50),1)))
#dataframe list
df <- split(df, df$f)
#Join to spatial data
s <- 1:2
lapply(X = s, FUN = function(x) dplyr::left_join(nd.l[[x]]@data, df[[x]]))
```

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: I must differ, it is minimal,complete and verifiable.